# Rake task not running from within worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rake, resque

I don't understand why my rake task is not running from within a resque worker. Running

```
rake :send_this_email
```

from the console works fine, I just want to run it as a cron job (as follows) but something is not working proplerly while invoking the rake task from within the worker.

My `rescue_schedule.yml`

```
send_this_email:
  cron: "*/2 * * * *"
  class: SendThisEmailWorker 
  args:
  description: "Send email when condition defined in rake task is met"
```

My `send_this_email_worker.rb` in `workers` directory, where the problem must be if I can manually call the rake task myself from the console?

```
require 'rake'

module SendThisEmailWorker
  @queue = :send_this_email

  def self.perform
    Rake::Task["send_this_email"].invoke
  end
end
```

When I start my dev server this `send_this_email` rake task should run every 2 minutes correct? It's not and the resque admin panel shows it as a job in the queue. What am I missing here?

Thanks for your attention.

UPDATED from gerep comment

```
require 'rake'

module SendThisEmailWorker
  @queue = :send_this_email

  def self.perform
    puts "Hi from the console, I'm started"
    Rake::Task["send_this_email"].invoke
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a worker started right? Just to test, put a "puts 'anything'" in your cronjob just to make sure it is called every 2 minutes, it will be printed in your console

Comment: I added the above and nothing has been printed to the console, my rake task also outputs to the console. Additionally, in the resque admin/interface I have the option to immediately start the job and when I do this the rake task is not invoked and no email received.

Comment: I believe I found the solution to my question here, I restarted my server with the following `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work rails s` https://github.com/defunkt/resque/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-ensure-my-rails-classesenvironment-is-loaded

Comment: Unfortunately, now when I try starting the rails server in dev mode this way I get the following. `Don't know how to build task 'rails'` last line when running with trace: `Execute resque:work` Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only `require 'rake'` is not enough. For example if you do
   Rake::Task.tasks #list down all task

You will get `[]`

You need to tell your worker class to load tasks.
Try this

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task.clear # necessary to avoid tasks being loaded several times in dev mode
YOUR_APP_NAME::Application.load_tasks
module SendThisEmailWorker
  @queue = :send_this_email

  def self.perform
    puts "Hi from the console, I'm started"
    Rake::Task["send_this_email"].invoke
  end
end
```

`YOUR_APP_NAME` is the name of your app and can be found at `config/application.rb`